# Pandas Create DataFrame with two lists behaving differently

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a pandas data frame using two lists and the output is erroneous for a given length of the lists.(this is not due to varying lengths)

Here I have two cases, one that works as expected and one that doesn't(commented out):

```
import string
d = dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_lowercase, 0).keys()
groups = sorted(d)[:3]
numList = range(0,4)
# groups = sorted(d)[:20]
# numList = range(0,25)

df = DataFrame({'Number':sorted(numList)*len(groups), 'Group':sorted(groups)*len(numList)})

df.sort_values(['Group', 'Number'])
```

Expected Output: every item in groups, to correspond to all items in numList

```
  Group Number 
    a   0
    a   1
    a   2
    a   3
    b   0
    b   1
    b   2
    b   3
    c   0
    c   1
    c   2
    c   3
```

Actual Results: Works for case in which lists are sized 3 and 4 but not 20 , and 25 (I have commented out that case in the above code)

Why is that? and how to fix that?

Comment: You can apply `print(df)` for both lists sized 3 and 4, and also 20 and 25 before implementing `df.sort_values(['Group', 'Number'])` to check the differences. From here, you can understand the root cause of the problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you want to make dataframe which will have all pairs of groups and numbers. That operation is called cartesian product. 
If the difference in lengths betweens those two arrays is exactly 1, it works with your approach, but this is more by pure accident. For general case, you want to do this.

```
df1 = DataFrame({'Number': sorted(numList)})
df2 = DataFrame({'Group': sorted(groups)})
df = df1.assign(key=1).merge(df2.assign(key=1), on='key').drop('key', 1)
```

And just note about dataframes sorting: You need to remember that in pandas, most of DataFrame operations return new DataFrame by default, don't modify the old one, unless you pass the `inplace=True` parameter. 
So you should do

```
df = df.sort_values(['Group', 'Number'])
```

or

```
df.sort_values(['Group', 'Number'], inplace=True)
```

and it should work now.

Comment: Your answer works, but I found another way by trial and error: I did a sort on numList*len(groups) and it worked perfecly well. But I am not sure why that is the case. df = ```DataFrame({'Number':sorted(numList*len(groups)), 'Group':sorted(groups)*len(numList)})``` Any ideas?  @Matěj Račinský